# Stored procedure returns different result than the query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has code something like this,

```
if Exists(select * from sysobjects where name = 'tblProducts_Details' and xtype = 'U')
begin
  Drop table tblProducts_Details
End

select * into tblProducts_Details from tblProducts

alter table tblProducts_Details add gcode varchar(50)

update a set a.gcode = b.gcode from tblProducts_Details a
inner join GroupID_GCode_Mapping b
on a.Company = b.Company

alter table tblProducts_Details add group_code int

update a set a.group_code = b.local_group_code from tblProducts_Details a  
inner join Cache.dbo.Z_MAP_GroupID_CGCode_Mapping b
on a.gcode = b.gcode

alter table tblProducts_Details add groupname varchar(2000)

update a set a.groupname = g.name from tblProducts_Details a 
inner join tblProductsGroup g
on a.group_code = g.group_id
```

When I execute the above query separately, it returns perfect result. But when I execute this stored procedure, sometimes it returns a different result set (some rows have different values than desired values).

I don't have any idea why.

Comment: Why are you using a persistent table for this? You may very well be having concurrency issues. You should be using a temp table for this.

Comment: I need to use these tables in another stored proc as well. That is why I am not using temp tables.

Comment: But the way you have it if more than 1 person runs your proc they are going to step on each other. Do you know that you can create a temp table in one proc and it will be available in a second one (assuming the second proc is called from within the first one)?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying tables (GroupID_GCode_Mapping,tblProductsGroup and Cache.dbo.Z_MAP_GroupID_CGCode_Mapping )must be changing between the execution of the stored procedure and when you check the results. There is nothing different about wrapping the whole thing in a proc. The update based on the 'cache' database may be taking a long time and by the time you realize the proc is done the data has changed.

Comment: Actually nothing is being modified in Z_MAP_GroupID_CGCode_Mapping table. I am just using it to update the group_code in tblProducts_Details table.

Comment: The only table being updated is tblProducts_Detail. What I think is happening is that you are running the proc at time A. At subsequent time B the underlying source tables are updated, then at time C when you compare what was updated they don't match. To really see what is being affected please add an output clause to the update statements. You can then see exactly what is being updated.